# C++ Read File Until Space

Tags: c++, ifstream

Is there a way I can read data from a file until a space? I have a file

`John J. Doe`

and I want to read the file and put `John` in 1 variable, `J.` in another variable and `Doe` in a final variable. How do I do this with ifstream?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just read the values into std::string variables, this will automatically tokenize it.

```
std::string fName, middleInit, lName;
my_stream >> fName >> middleInit >> lName;
```

Comment: Is it possible to change tokenizing char like a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Is this your file name or file content? I assume it's file content.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
//..........
ifstream fin;
fin.open("your file", ifstream::in);
string var1, var2, var3;
fin>> var 1 >> var2 >> var 3;
```

Comment: This works     ifstream file_parse;
file_parse.open(file_name, ios::in);
string var1, var2, var3;
file_parse >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;
cout << "var1 " << var1 << endl;
cout << "var2 " << var2 << endl;  Now I need to have var[] as an array . How ?

Comment: int index;
 ifstream file_parse_array;
 file_parse_array.open(file_name, ios::in);
#define MAX_ARRAY 256
 string var[MAX_ARRAY]; // 
 for (index = 1; index < MAX_ARRAY; index++) {
  file_parse_array >> var[index]; // 
  if (var[index].empty())
   continue;
  cout << "var[index] " << var[index] << endl;

 }